# $\int_3^5{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx}$ by differentiation under the integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying an easy problem to get my bearings using the method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/).

The integral is
$$\int_3^5{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx}$$.

I would like to proceed, if possible to solve by defining:

$$F(y) = \int_3^5{\frac{\sin{(y\cdot x})}{1+x^2}dx}$$

Then obtaining $$-F''(y) = \int_3^5{\frac{x^2\sin{(y\cdot x})}{1+x^2}dx}$$

Adding gives $$F(y) - F''(y)= \int_3^5{\frac{(1+x^2)\sin{(y\cdot x})}{1+x^2}dx}$$

or  $$F(y) - F''(y) - \frac{\cos{3y}-\cos{5y}}{y} = 0.$$

This is where I'm stuck.  I don't know how to solve the differential equation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm assuming that this can be done.

Comment: If you use cos instead of sin, then $-F''(y)$ will be just what you're looking for when $y=0$.  Then, for $(\sin 3y - \sin 5y)/y$, you'd find the limit as $y\to0$.

Comment: @Michael Hardy:  F(y) would still be part of the result, though, wouldn't it?  I'm trying not to integrate the denominator at all if possible.  My goal is to avoid integrating the fractions.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: $F(0)$ must be involved as well.

Comment: This is really roundabout, but doable. Using the original version with $\sin$, the result will have the form of $F$ in terms of an integral, but you need $F'(0)$ for your final answer so it disappears. One way is to solve $u-y''=\cos(kt)/t$ by introducing $v=u'$ and then writing the second-order DE as a first-order system ($\vec{q}=(u,v)^T$) $$q'=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}q-{0\choose\cos(kt)/t}$$ which can be solved using [an integrating factor with the matrix exponential](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34228/does-this-ode-question-have-closed-form-solution/55124#55124).

Comment: As anon mentions, I should say that calculating limits should be easy for what I anticipate - hence I can get F(0), F''(0), and so on...  Thanks to anon, by the way.

Comment: That should be $u-u''$ in my above comment. I'd expand in an answer but not feeling up to it right now. Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's observe the next differential equation:

$y''-y+ \frac{\cos3x-\cos5x}{x}=0$ ,

This is nonhomogeneous second-order ordinary differential equation of the form:
$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y-g(x)=0$ ,which can be solved if the general solution to the homogenous version is known, in which case variation of parameters can be used to find the particular solution:

$y_p=-y_1(x)\int\frac{y_2(x)g(x)}{W(x)}\, dx + y_2(x)\int\frac{y_1(x)g(x)}{W(x)}\, dx$ , where $y_p$ is particular solution, $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are the homogeneous solutions of the equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ and  W(x) is the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Definition) of these two functions.